# Ajax request in extjs fires success although response is false

Tags: ajax, extjs

I have an AJAX request like:

```
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'login.php',
            scope: me,
            params: {
              email: 'test@gg.com',
              password: '12345',
            },
            
            success: function(){console.log('OK');}, 
            failure: function(){console.log('ERROR');},   
            
        });
```

The console.log is 'OK', even though the response is false

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure callback fires only if an HTTP status returned from the server is different than **200 OK**.

Change the status in response or check the value of `success` parameter just in `success` callback.

Answer (score 1):

The success callback function has two return arguments, the first is the response from the server. Decoding the response will allow you to check for a successful login, something like this:

```
success: function(response, opts) {
    var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    if (obj.success === true) console.log('success!');
}
```

Comment: The other problem is that the response is not received until script is finished, so there is no response.responseText at that moment.

Comment: Success is the callback function that is executed when the server response is received by the client. Response is an object that contains the data that is returned by the request. You might want to look at the docs - https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.Ajax.html#method-request for more detail.